# Simple PDE classification question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Benjamin-Bona-Mahony equation:
$$\displaystyle u_t+u_x+uu_x-u_{xxt}=0$$
both the paper I was reading and wikipedia claimed that it is nonlinear. It has been some time since I studied classification so I wasn't sure it is nonlinear because of $uu_x$ or $u_{xxt}$ or both.

So I looked it up and found that
"... semilinear equations are ones in which the coeﬃcients of
the terms involving the highest-order derivatives of u depend only on x, not on u or its
derivatives."
And claims that $$\displaystyle u_t+u_{xxx}+u u_{x}=0$$ 
is semiliner.

So it seems to me that if BBM is indeed nonlinear, it is not because of $uu_{x}$, but because of $u_{xxt}$, but that feels unnatural for me.

Please shed some light on me.

Comment: the quoted definition seems incomplete. Some coefficient depends on $u$ so that makes it nonlinear, if the coefficient is for a lower order derivative then the classification relaxes to  semi-linear.

Comment: semi-linear is not linear.

Comment: @TCL Not linear and linear were never mentioned, or do you imply that ''not linear'' is equivalent to nonlinear?

Comment: It is nonlinear b/c of $uu_x$, not b/c of $u_{xxt}$.

Comment: @TLC 2nd equation also has $uu_x$, but it was claimed as semi-linear not nonlinear, why?

Comment: To call a semilinear equation nonlinear is correct logically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider first order PDE depending on two independent variables. It is

- linear, if it has the form
  $$
  a(x,y)\partial_x u+b(x,y)\partial_yu=c(x,y)u+f(x,y),
  $$
  Example:
  $$
  \partial_xu+\partial_yu=0.
  $$
- semi-linear if it has the form
  $$
  a(x,y)\partial_x u+b(x,y)\partial_yu=c(x,y,u),
  $$
  Example:
  $$
  \partial_xu+\partial_yu=u^2
  $$
- quasi-linear if it has the form
  $$
  a(x,y,u)\partial_x u+b(x,y,u)\partial_yu=c(x,y,u),
  $$
  Example:
  $$
  \partial_xu+u\partial_yu=0
  $$
- fully non-linear if it has the form
  $$
  F(x,y,u,\partial_xu,\partial_yu)=0.
  $$
  Example:
  $$
  (\partial_xu)^2+(\partial_yu)^2=V(x,y).
  $$

Note that semi-linear, quasi-linear, and fully nonlinear equations are *nonlinear.*

Can you generalize this classification to equations of any order?

Comment: For generalization, the second order and linear would be $a(x,y)\partial_{xx} u+b(x,y)\partial_{yy}u=c(x,y)u+f(x,y)$ ?