# Classificiation of the Pde $w_{xxxx}+4w_{xy}=2 \tan x $

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$w_{xxxx}+4w_{xy}=2 \tan x $

Is the pde quasi-linear, semi-linear or fully non-linear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is linear. Indeed if $w_1$ and $w_2$ are solutions of the homogenous equation
$$w_{xxxx} + w_{xy} = 0$$
then $w_1 + w_2$ is also solution.

Comment: Can you generalize it for other questions pls ? Specially, I don't understand  the questions including terms $w_{xy}$

Comment: What questions ?

Comment: $$w_{xxx} + 2w_{xy}+w_{yy} = sinx$$. how to show that it is linear, semi linear , quasi linear or non linear ? Could you explain pls ?

Comment: Your equation is linear. Go check http://math.stackexchange.com/a/389382/427673

Comment: I checked. But there is no terms $u_{xy} $ in the definition ?