# What it means that a function depends on $x,y,u,u_x,u_y$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

Definition: A PDE equation is quasilinear if $Au_{xx}+Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_x+Eu_y+Fu+G+\Phi(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)=0,$ where $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ are functions of $x,y,u.$

Is this equation quasilinear? $$(x^2+u^2)u_x-xyu_y=u^3x+y^2$$

The answer is yes it is because $D=(x^2+u^2),E=-xy,F=u^2x, G=y^2$.

However in this pdf http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-%20Guwahati/maths3/module_13/pdenotes.pdf pag. [2] says that 
$xu_x+yu_y+u^2=0$ is not linear, semilinear nor quasilinear. And I don't understand why, according to definition it's quasilinear.

So maybe I'm not understanding correctly  the meaning of *function of..* or maybe the pdf file is wrong.

Comment: Do not delete my tags :/

Comment: Your question is not about function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition in the note:

> A PDE is said to be quasilinear if it is linear in its highest derivative. That is, the
>   coefficient of highest order does not depend on any highest order partial derivative.

So the PDE $xu_x + yu_y +u^2 = 0$ IS quasilinear. Indeed in the note it is not claimed that the above is NOT quasilinear. It said that it is "nonlinear".

The $xu_x + yu_y +u^2 = 0$ is not linear because of that $u^2$ term. Thus it is nonlinear. (So it is both quasilinear and nonlinear).

Comment: Did you read definition 1.7? It says PDE is nonlinear if it doesn't belong to any of the three types.

Comment: The only possible conclusion is that the notes have it wrong:  $xu_x + yu_y +u^2 = 0$ is, according to Def. 1.5, semilinear, so it is not, according to Def. 1.7, nonlinear.

Comment: See [Simple PDE classification question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388389/simple-pde-classification-question) for another definition.